# Javascript: sort multiple arrays with two possible items

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array containing a bunch of arrays, where every one of these arrays has the same length and just two possible entries (+1 and -1 or +1 and 0). Now I'm searching for an efficient way to sort these arrays, so if I want to check if the list contains a given array, there is no need to compare the given array with every one in the list.

The list may look like this:

```
list = [
  [1, 1, -1, 1],
  [-1, 1, -1, 1],
  [1, -1, -1, 1]
];
```

To be more precise, this list is created in a while loop, where the condition is that the new array created in the loop does not appear in the list yet. Therefore, it would be nice to sort the array on the fly, e.g. insert it at an appropriate place in the list.

To avoid misunderstandings, the loop now looks like this

```
var list = [];
var array = someArray;
while (indexOfArray(list, array) === -1) {
  list.push(array);
  array = calculateNewArray(array);
}
```

where indexOfArray is a function that returns the index of the array in list if existing, -1 otherwise, and calculateArray takes the previous array and returns a new one. The problem is that the list may get very long (thousands or tens of thousands of different arrays, which may have a length of several hundred entries), so always compare the new array with every saved array in the list becomes extremely time consuming.

What is an efficient and sound approach to tackle this problem?

**Edit:** to provide an example, the list above could be sorted as

```
sortedList = sortList(list)
// sortedList should look like this
[
  [1, 1, -1, 1],
  [1, -1, -1, 1]
  [-1, 1, -1, 1],
]
```

where first comes the array containing as many +1 in a row as possible, second the one with least fewer +1 and so and, while the last array contains as many -1 as possible in a row.

Comment: Do these need to be arrays? Couldn't you just store strings like `00101` or numbers (`parseInt(..., 2)`) ?

Comment: please add some examples.

Comment: So, if I understand you right, you generate 3^n arrays with non-reapating values. There is a much easier way to achieve this without need to sort, insert or search.

Comment: @georg: it is not absolutely necessary, but quite handy because I use these array for further calculations

Comment: @Yeldar: would you mind explaining your idea?

Comment: @Madao I didn't understand what results you actually try to achieve. As I said before, if you need to make 3^n different arrays with -1, 0 and 1 values, you can simply make a for-loop from 0 to 3^n - 1 and generate arrays in 3-based numeric system - 1. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/45putrxy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and simply add all values of the inner array.

```js
// the array to be sorted
var list = [[1, 1, -1, 1], [-1, 1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1, 1]];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = list.map(function (el, i) {
    return { index: i, value: el.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0) };
});

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return list[el.index];
});

console.log(result);
```

Edit for in situ sorting

Basically, you have two options

1. use a property for it. (the property `sum` remains until it became deleted)

```js
var list = [[1, 1, -1, 1], [-1, 1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1, 1]];

list.forEach(function (el) {
    el.sum = el.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
});

list.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.sum - a.sum;
});

console.log(list);
```

2. get for every sort loop the sums (does not need a property, but the perfomance is bad)

```js
function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }

var list = [[1, 1, -1, 1], [-1, 1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1, 1]];

list.sort(function (a, b) {        
    return b.reduce(sum, 0) - a.reduce(sum, 0);
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! Is there a more efficient way to add a new array than to push it and sort the whole list again?

Answer (score 0):

You could just map through the `list` and sort all the inner arrays with `sort()`.

```js
list = [
  [1, 1, -1, 1],
  [-1, 1, -1, 1],
  [1, -1, -1, 1]
];

list = list.map(function(x){return x.sort(function(a,b){return a-b})});

console.log(list);
```

It could be even shorter with Javascript ES6:

```
list = list.map(x=>x.sort((a,b)=>(a-b)));
```

Comment: I did not mean to sort the elements of the arrays (they need to be in a specific order), but to sort, e.g. change the order of the arrays themselves

Comment: @Madao, please supply some examples. otherwise its just guessing what you want.

Comment: @nicael, sorting is in situ, no need to map.